# Codeigniter Upload CSV to Database

Tags: php, database, codeigniter, csv

thank you in advance for the help you give me, I'll explain my situation.
Based on tutorial

[File uploading](http://ellislab.com/codeigniter/user-guide/libraries/file_uploading.html)

[Forum : Just a nice csv upload and populate the database function](http://ellislab.com/forums/viewthread/135217/#667613)

[Form creating insert data](http://www.phpeveryday.com/articles/CodeIgniter-Form-Creating-Insert-Data-P248.html)

I'm trying to make a page that allows me to upload a CSV file, parse this document and inserting data into my database.
I've written up to now this code:

```
<?php

class Upload extends CI_Controller {

function __construct()
{
    parent::__construct();
    $this->load->helper(array('form', 'url'));
}

function index()
{
    $this->load->view('upload_form', array('error' => ' ' ));
}

function do_upload(){
    $config['upload_path'] = './uploads/';
    $config['allowed_types'] = 'csv';
    $config['max_size']  = '5000';
    $with = ' ';
    $replace = '"';

    $this->load->library('upload', $config);
    $this->load->database();

    if ( ! $this->upload->do_upload())
    {
        $error = array('error' => $this->upload->display_errors());
        $this->load->view('upload_form', $error);
    }
    else
    {
//Insert file info into database
$data = array('upload_data' => $this->upload->data());
$userfile = $data['upload_data']['file_name'];
$this->load->library('csvreader');
$filePath1 = './uploads/';
$filePath2 = $data['upload_data']['file_name'];
$filePath = $filePath1 . $filePath2;
$data['csvData'] = $this->csvreader->parse_file($filePath);
foreach($data['csvData'] as $cd){
    $results_array = array(
                           'Parolachiave' => $cd['Parola chiave'],
                           'Concorrente' => $cd['Concorrente'],
                           'Motorediricerca' => $cd['Motore di ricerca'],
                           'Posizione' => $cd['Posizione'],
                           'Paginaweb' => $cd['Pagina web'],
                           'Modifiche' => $cd['Modifiche']
                           );        
           $this->db->set($results_array);
           $this->db->insert('data', $results_array);


        } 
    } 
 }
}
?>
```

I use google chrome and gives me this error: HTTP Error 500 (Internal Server Error) when I try to entries in index.php / upload.
I have declared my database in config / database.php in the root of Codeigniter.
I'm trying to network the solution to my problem but I still have not figured out where I'm wrong.
Thank you.

This is my library/csvreader.php

```
<?php if (!defined('BASEPATH')) exit('No direct script access allowed');
class CSVReader {

var $fields;        /** columns names retrieved after parsing */
var $separator = ',';    /** separator used to explode each line */

/**
 * Parse a text containing CSV formatted data.
 *
 * @access    public
 * @param    string
 * @return    array
 */
function parse_text($p_Text) {
    $lines = explode("\n", $p_Text);
    return $this->parse_lines($lines);
}

/**
 * Parse a file containing CSV formatted data.
 *
 * @access    public
 * @param    string
 * @return    array
 */
function parse_file($p_Filepath) {
    $lines = file($p_Filepath);
    return $this->parse_lines($lines);
}
/**
 * Parse an array of text lines containing CSV formatted data.
 *
 * @access    public
 * @param    array
 * @return    array
 */
function parse_lines($p_CSVLines) {
    $content = FALSE;
    foreach( $p_CSVLines as $line_num => $line ) {
        if( $line != '' ) { // skip empty lines
            $elements = split($this->separator, $line);

            if( !is_array($content) ) { // the first line contains fields names
                $this->fields = $elements;
                $content = array();
            } else {
                $item = array();
                foreach( $this->fields as $id => $field ) {
                    if( isset($elements[$id]) ) {
                        $item[$field] = $elements[$id];
                    }
                }
                $content[] = $item;
            }
        }
    }
    return $content;
}
}
```

Comment: Why there is a space after `$`

Comment: Watch your php logs and give us the last fatal errors

Comment: @dianuj I would say, why is there spaces everywhere in the code...

Comment: @Brewal exactly too much spaces

Comment: Sorry for the much spaces and sorry for the question i'm a newbie in programming, but where i can see the logs in  phpmyadmin? thanks

Answer (score 0):

```
if ($ this-> upload-> do_upload ())
```

There should be a `!` before the `$` sign, so that clause part becomes the error part, and at the else part you can go on.

And

```
do_upload function ()
```

This should be

```
function do_upload()
```

Also too much spaces that breaks syntax, which possibly causes the error.

Comment: I edit my code, im sorry i used google translate and it changed my code.

Comment: You declared a function inside a function, that is what causing the error, 

function entry_insert(){

delete the function declaration

Comment: Thanks the problem was precisely the function within the function.
Now I log in on the upload page but when I try to load a csv file comes out the following message: "The filetype you are attempting to upload is not allowed". And then if I go to see the table data of the db is empty. Thank u.

Comment: @ValeBoccaccio Which version of CodeIgniter are you using, and are you on a Windows based hosting?

Comment: I use the last versione of Codeigniter 2.1.3, i work on windows 7 and my web server is:
   
MySQL

Server: Localhost via UNIX socket
Versione MySQL: 5.1.61-0ubuntu0.11.04.1
Set di caratteri MySQL: UTF-8 Unicode (utf8)

Web server

Apache/2.2.17 (Ubuntu)
Versione MySQL client: 5.1.61
Estensioni PHP: mysqli

phpMyAdmin

Informazioni sulla versione: 3.3.10deb1

Comment: You still have a function inside a function (function entry_insert(){) , delete that, that should work. Also , for CSV, check this question (the accepted answer): http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4731071/uploading-a-csv-into-codeigniter

Comment: Thank upload works now there are no errors, but does not load anything on the database. I have a problem in the code of upload.php in the part of //Insert CSV Data into Database. In fact I would like to parse and insert data into the database, and because of this code does not insert anything

Comment: The connection to the database is working because if I go to see my table in the database I found 0 for each field.

Comment: I can't quite say what's going wrong there, since you didn't provide the HTML form, try echoing the mysql_error(); or refer to: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1893381/codeigniter-continue-on-sql-error

Comment: I edited my code now so entering the data into the database works.
I need to change my code now so that:
1) create a new table in the database each time by assigning the name of the csv file that load
2) 'Pagina web' is a url, I have to parse the domain of this url before placing it in the database and enter only the domain in the database
Seeking suggestions thanks