# Jquery Ajax Shows error 500 when ever sql returns error

Tags: javascript, php, jquery, ajax, codeigniter

I am Working on Codeigniter and am getting a problem while inserting values in database via ajax.
Problem occur when sql query throws an error. 
This is My Controller code:-

```
public function Register_data()
{
    $data = array(
        'user_name'=>$this->input->post('name'),
        'user_email'=>$this->input->post('emailid'),
        'user_pwd'=>$this->input->post('pwd'),
        'user_pno'=>$this->input->post('pno'),
        'user_gender'=>$this->input->post('gender'),
        'user_age'=>$this->input->post('age'),
        'dor'=>date('Y-m-d H:i:s'),);
    $this->load->model('Register');
    $this->Register->insert_content($data);
    $output = array(); //Creating output array for json response to ajax
    $output['result'] = $this->Register->getStatus();    echo $output['result'].'---';
    $output['message'] = $this->Register->getMessage();  echo $output['message'];
    echo json_encode($output);
}
```

My Model code is so :-

```
class Register extends CI_Model{
var $message;
var $status;
public function __construct() 
{
    parent::__construct();
    $this->load->database();
}
public function insert_content($da)
{   
    if ($this->db->insert('user',$da))//Checking if mysql query is successful
    {
        $this->status = true;
        $this->message = "DATA INSERTED";
    }
    else
    {
        $this->status = false;
        $this->message = $this->db->error_message();            
    }
}
public function getStatus()
{
    return $this->status;
}
public function getMessage()
{
    return $this->message;
}}
```

And this is My Ajax Call:-

```
$.ajax({
    url: "<?php echo site_url('Home_Controller/Register_data');?>",
    data: $("#frm").serialize(),
    type: 'POST',
    success: function (data) {
        alert(data);
        var resp = $.parseJSON(data);
        if (resp.result) {
            window.location.href = "<?php echo site_url('Home_Controller');?>";
        } else {
            $("#msgs").html(resp.message);
        }
    },
    error: function (error) {
        $("#msgs").html(JSON.stringify(error)); //This is returned when model condition for inserting data throws error.
    }
});
```

[image: Red Color text is an error which is displayed when sql duplication occurs]

And please note that datas are getting inserted. Hence there is no problem while inserting. I have used json to return as response to ajax. Problem occurs only when inserting goes wrong. Example:- I have kept email as unique in database hence when i insert duplicate in db then mysql throws an error that says duplication error, as u can see my code in model that i have made insert code in if condition and that when insert query gets failed status and msg are stored in a variable. This is how i used to do in core php. I have no idea about how to handle this in codeigniter. Kindly provide a good solutions. Any Help Will be appreciated.

Comment: Check this link... It may help you http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1893381/codeigniter-continue-on-sql-error

Comment: Thanx Ashwani, because of your post i have solved this problem

Answer (score 0):

Codeigniter has included error() function to display db error. db->error_message() was the problem hear